# A Windows Mobile 6.0 application can be run on Windows CE 6.0?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile, windows-ce, barcode-scanner

Hello and thank you for reading my post.

I have an application for Windows Mobile 6.0 and now the client wants to buy a new devices that come with Windows CE 6.0. My question is that if my palicación can work with these new devices?

Thanks in advance directly for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Running apps compiled against a Windwos Mobile (WM) SDK will normally not run on Windows CE devices (WCE). Windows Mobile is, among others, a shell on top of Windows CE. Normally apps compiled for WM use functions of aygshell.dll which is not available on WCE devices.

If you have luck, the app is a Compact Framework application and does not explicitely use any WM specific API. In that case the app may run on a WCE device without a change.

Further possible causes for not working are the different processors available with WCE devices in contrast to more or less actual WM devices using an ARM XScale processor.

WCE is not a standard OS like WM. WCE is fully configurable by the OEM. There are the old XBOX, navigation systems and other devices running a Windows CE based OS. These need not to be certified or verified by Microsoft. But every Windows Mobile, Windows Embdedded Handheld and former PocketPC device and OS build of an OEM has to be cerfified by Microsoft. This garanties a defined API set and common shell is available on the WM device.

Just get a real test device and check if the app runs on that, there are chances that it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: what Device manufacturer Do you have? With intermec, Motorola, datalogic and so on you won't have an Problems unless you use functions which are only available on Windows mobile. But you can determine if you Run on wce or WM. In Visual Studio you can switch a smart Device project from ce to WM and back. There are only few limitations. Even the generated cab-files you can use on both Devices. Feel free to ask for more Details.